# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (trying to connect to Essbase)

Tags: python, essbase

Hi I'm trying to connect to Essbase, and I'm getting an error. Any help in resolving this is appreciated.

class Essbase:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.user = None
    self.sid = None
    self.ssnInit = None
    self.numRows = None
    self.numFlds = None
    self.sts = None
    self.bMdxQuery = None

    # Check for environment variables needed for essbase
    try:
        os.environ["ESSBASEPATH"]
        os.environ["PATH"]
    except KeyError as e:
        print ("environment variable {VAR} not set".format(VAR=e))
        raise SystemExit

    # Initialize MaxL API
    inst = maxl_instinit_t()

    # Try to find and load the DLL
    __maxldll = find_library('essmaxlu')
    if __maxldll:
        print ("Using Maxl DLL in {DLLpath}".format(DLLpath = __maxldll))
        if "11.1.2.4" in (getFileVerInfo(__maxldll)):
            MAXL_MDXCELLSTRSZ           = 1024 + 3
        else:
            MAXL_MDXCELLSTRSZ           = 1024
        self.maxl = cdll.LoadLibrary(__maxldll)
    else:
        print ("maxl DLL not found")
        raise SystemExit

    if ESS_UTF:
        inst.bUTFInput = ESS_TRUE

    sts = self.maxl.MaxLInit(byref(inst))
    Essbase.isInitialized = (sts == MAXL_MSGLVL_SUCCESS)

def __del__(self):
    if Essbase.isInitialized:
        # Terminate MaxL API
        sts = self.maxl.MaxLTerm()
        Essbase.isInitialized = False
```

I'm getting below error message...

Using Maxl DLL in C:\ORACLE\Middleware\EPMSystem11R1\common\EssbaseRTC-64\11.1.2.0\bin\essmaxlu.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 40, in 
    esss = Essbase.Essbase()

File "C:\Python3\Lib\Essbase.py", line 184, in **init**
    if "11.1.2.4" in (getFileVerInfo(__maxldll)):

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: How to solve your problem is in your error message.  It's entirely unrelated to essbase.

Comment: Could you give me a hint? I'm stuck in this error for a couple hours now.

Comment: `if b'11.1.2.34' in (getFileVerInfo(__maxldll)):`

Comment: See: https://github.com/jasonwjones/essbasepy/issues/4

Comment: Thank you everyone! I was able to clear this error with TheIncorrigible1's advice but now I'm getting a different error about OSError: exception: access violation. I'll check the github link as well.

Comment: There was an outstanding pull request that fixes the issue (prefixing the string with `b` as @TheIncorrigible1 mentions. It's now merged into master for anyone in the future that might run across this